# Unable to install plotly and devtools in rstudio server installed in Ubuntu on AWS?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, plotly, rstudio-server

I have created an EC2 instance in AWS(with Ubuntu), installed r studio server, but when I am trying to install the `plotly` package it gives an error related to OpenSSL:

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing: 
* deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc) 
* rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL) 
* csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris) 
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH
and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config is unavailable
you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: 
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
------------------------------------------------------------‌-------
```

Also, I have tried to install `devtools` but no luck. Please help as this is the only part where I am stuck?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the exact error messages. Most likely you are missing some *-dev packages.

Comment: ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you, you need to install (the development files for) `libcurl`:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

There might be more such error messages down the road.

An interesting alternative to manual installation is to use binary packages, since their dependencies are handled automatically. See http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/12/22/#014_finding_binary_deb_packages for details.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install r-cran-plotly
```

In earlier Ubuntu releases than Ubuntu 18.04 plotly can be installed with the following commands:

```
sudo R -e "install.packages('ggplot2', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
sudo R -e "install.packages('plotly', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```